# Image not showing up in runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to display an image from the folder which is created under the project directory by name Images.

I'm trying to access `star.gif` which is inside the Images folder.

Here is my small piece of code for accessing the images

```
TableCell tc=new TableCell();                  

for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{

    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image rating = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
    rating.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("~/Images/star.gif");
    rating.ID = j.ToString();
    rating.AlternateText = "No image";

    tc.Controls.Add(rating);
}
```

I even set the authorization in `web.config` but its of no use.

Kindly tell my mistake in the code.

Comment: Unless there is a specific reason otherwise, you shouldn't have to use `Server.MapPath()`.  Try inspecting the path to be sure it's pointing to the right location.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove [**Server.MapPath**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). This call will return **a physical location on your server**, which is *not accessible on the client*!

**MSDN Server.MapPath**

> The MapPath method maps the specified relative or virtual 
>   path to the corresponding physical directory on the server.

**new code**

```
TableCell tc=new TableCell();  
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image rating = new  System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
    rating.ImageUrl = "~/Images/star.gif"; // no need for Server.MapPath
    rating.ID = j.ToString();
    rating.AlternateText = "No image";
    tc.Controls.Add(rating);
}
```

Comment: In this case, pls consider voting my answer up and/or marking it as best answer! thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

`Server.MapPath` is going to return a local path on the server, e.g. `C:\Images\star.gif`. Your browser will not be able to resolve that url.

Just use the relative url:

```
rating.ImageUrl = "~/Images/star.gif";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the runat attribute so that it resolves from the root?

```
rating.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
rating.ImageUrl = "~/Images/star.gif";
```